# numpy array sliced twice

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I'm not sure I understand why this doesn't work :

```
a = np.zeros((10, ))

# first slicing array
pos1 = np.zeros((10, ), dtype=np.bool)
pos1[::2] = True

a[pos1] = 1.
print a
# returns [ 1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]


# second slicing array
pos2 = np.zeros((5, ), dtype=np.bool)
pos2[::2] = True

a[pos1][pos2] = 2.

print a
# still returns [ 1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
```

why does the second slicing didn't affect the full array?
I thought `a[pos1]` was just a "view" of the subpart of the original array... Am I missing something?

(this example is just a simple example with no real use, it is just to try to understand cause I'm using this kind of syntax a lot and I didn't expect this result)

Comment: Probably has to do with it being an assignment, .... being on the left-hand-side.

Comment: Just looking at it, it appears that you are trying to assign a value to a subset of a 2d array.  During assignment, *it* must not be creating a temporary array from ```a[pos1]```.  You would have to dig into the docs or maybe even the source to find the answer.

Comment: Boolean indexing is a type of ["advanced indexing"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing); this is not the same as slicing and does not give a view into the original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same issue as in recent [Numpy doesn't change value of an array element after masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001767/numpy-doesnt-change-value-of-an-array-element-after-masking)

You are using a boolean mask, so `a[pos1]` is a copy, not a slice.

The first set works because it is a direct call to `__setitem__`:

```
a[pos1] = 1.
a.__setitem__(pos1) = 1
```

The second does not because the `set` applies to `a[pos1]`, a copy:

```
a[pos1][pos2] = 2.
a.__getitem__(pos1).__setitem__(pos2)
```

`a[::2][pos2]=3` does work because `a[::2]` is a slice - even though it produces the same values as `a[pos1]`.

One way to check whether something is a copy or view is to look at the array's data pointer

```
 a.__array_interface__['data']
 a[pos1].__array_interface__['data'] # will be different
 a[::2].__array_interface__['data']  # should be the same
```

Comment: thank you! Sorry for the duplicate, I didn't find this question/answer... same problem indeed! :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the python byte code (outputs of [dis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html)) when we define the following three functions:

```
In [187]: def b():
    a[pos1][pos2]=2
    return a

In [188]: dis.dis(b)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (pos1)
              9 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             10 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (pos2)
             13 STORE_SUBSCR        

  3          14 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
             17 RETURN_VALUE        

In [189]: b()
Out[189]: array([ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.])




In [190]: def c():
    e=a.copy()
    e[pos1][pos2]=2
    return e

In [191]: dis.dis(c)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (copy)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (e)

  3          12 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (e)
             18 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (pos1)
             21 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             22 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (pos2)
             25 STORE_SUBSCR        

  4          26 LOAD_FAST                0 (e)
             29 RETURN_VALUE 

In [191]: c()
Out[191]: array([ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.])




In [192]: def d():
    f=a[pos1]
    f[pos2]=2
    return f

In [193]: dis.dis(d)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (pos1)
              6 BINARY_SUBSCR       
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (f)

  3          10 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
             13 LOAD_FAST                0 (f)
             16 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (pos2)
             19 STORE_SUBSCR        

  4          20 LOAD_FAST                0 (f)
             23 RETURN_VALUE  

In [194]: d()
Out[194]: array([ 2.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  2.])
```

From the disassembled code, each time the `a[pos1][pos2]=2` assignment is performed, it is indeed stored in the top of the stack but then, global (case 1) or the local (case 2) variables are returned instead. 
When you split the operations (case 3), the interpreter seems to all at sudden remember that it had just stored the value on the stack and does not need to reload it.

Comment: the function ``d()`` does not work neither... it's because you returned ``f = a[pos1]`` instead of ``a``. If you print ``a`` it still doesn't have any ``2.``