# Understanding views/copies of Python numpy arrays: why doesn't a double boolean index work?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean-operations

I am reading http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html (and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) and trying to understand why Python would not attempt to interpret the last line in the following in an intuitive way,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
n = 100
tested = np.zeros(n, dtype=bool)
dt = pd.DatetimeIndex([pd.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
    + pd.Timedelta(minutes=idx) for idx in range(n)])

data = np.random.normal(size=n)
data[np.random.uniform(size=n) > 0.9] = np.nan
mask = np.isnan(data)

dt_ = dt[~mask]
data_ = data[~mask]
select = pd.DatetimeIndex(dt_) > pd.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
data__ = data_[select]  # do something with this later, otherwise, why mask?

tested[~mask][select] = True # or np.ones(select.sum(), dtype=bool)
```

i.e., please, Python gods, update those elements of `tested` masked by first *and* second boolean arrays. It is is quite annoying that the first boolean mask returns a *copy* (thanks for the catch @user2357112) of the `tested` array that, when indexed and updated by the second, does not write the results back into the original array. I think I am right is saying that some other interpreted languages use such syntax, why not here? Or perhaps there is some computer science best-practices that I am not understanding correctly? Whereas what actually happens is that `tested` is still a vector of boolean of all `False`.

Comment: `tested[~mask]` returns a copy, not a view.  Indexing with a scalar or a slice (`:`) produces a `view`, but indexing with boolean or list produces a copy.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that would give you a SettingWithCopyWarning if NumPy had that warning.

Comment: As explained above, I understand this. The question is, why doesn't Python, in which generators and other such line-saving syntax are available, allow me to simply update a few elements of an array as explained above? What advantages does Python gain with the copy-vs-view approach?  (And thanks for the quick responses)

Comment: Your explanation claims it's a view, so it doesn't really sound like you understand it.

Comment: You're right, I put the wrong word in that spot, good catch. My question is more related to the design choice in python.

Comment: My answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063014/numpy-array-sliced-twice shows how Python translates the `x[...][...] =` syntax.  It may make the action clearer.  `numpy` runs in Python.  The Python interpreter is still king.  Each `[]` translates into a `__getitem__` or `__setitem__` call.

Comment: excellent, I used a bunch of search terms trying to find such a post, but apparently was not thorough enough...I guess we just need another of the same post with a different title.

Comment: With these explanation being similar to the link I posted above as having read...I am still a little confused by the design choice, why does Python (or Numpy) use a copy-vs-view framework in which I must make a copy of an array before I can sub-index it with another boolean vector? Is this a common paradigm in most languages?

Comment: What other languages do you have in mind? View vs. Copy is a numpy idea.  The closest thing in python is deep vs shallow copy.

Comment: I'm not sure, ticking them off in my head, not many actually have the option to do boolean indexing. Maybe this is just wishful thinking and there is no getting around the `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` functions...

Comment: The problem, it seems, it that when I request a subset of items via boolean index, the call doesn't know what I'm going to do with the results. It would be convenient if python/numpy has a way specifying for what the result of the `__getitem__` will be used, e.g., `tested.multi_index([~mask],[selected]) = True`

Comment: Except for the shared data buffer of a view, `__getitem__` result does not maintain a link to the original array.  There's no reverse mapping or indexing.

Answer (score 0):

The key to using both `mask` and `select` is change `~mask` to indices, and apply `select` to that array.

```
print(select.shape)
print(data__.shape)

idx = np.where(~mask)[0]
tested[idx[select]] = True
print(tested.sum())
```

producing for one run:

```
(92,)
(34,)
34
```

I've found with timing tests that `data[mask]` is effectively `data[np.where(mask)]`, so there's no loss in power to use array selection rather than boolean masking.

If this kind of double masking occurred often enough, `numpy` developers could package this code in a function, even in compiled code.

```
data[mask][select] = 1   # translates to:
data.__getitem__(mask).__setitem__(select, 1)
```

is consistent Python syntax.  If you want different interpreter action, such as:

```
data.__setitem__(<foo(mask, select)>, 1)
```

write a PEP, and convince other Python developers that it is a good idea.